# meaning of "this.el" in $('ul', this.el)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am just going through some backbone tutorials and I have a general jQuery question that I have actually been wondering for a while.

Sometimes I see calls with a second parameter in the jQuery selector, for example `$('ul', this.el)`.

What is the purpose of this second param in the selector? And I don't really mean in context of any backbone examples, just in general what is the purpose of passing the second param in the selector and why is it always an object that is passed there? I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: was looking for it... couldn't find it. thanks for the link though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It narrows the search for a `ul` tag within your view component's DOM element.

Comment: Ah, nice! I thought it was doing something like that just couldn't verbalize it to myself. Thanks!

Comment: btw, do you know if there are any performance benefits to doing it like that rather than $(this.el).find('ul'); or $(this.el+' ul'); or is it essentially the same?

Answer (score 13):

The meaning is identical to:

```
$(this.el).find('ul')
```

Internally, after a bunch of tests, jQuery figures out that it needs to flip it around to the above `.find()` call, so it does, and starts over.

So providing the context as the second argument is just a slower way to do a `.find()`.

[Here it is in the source.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L170-175)

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, context)
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
}
```

...where `this.constructor` is the `$` function, `context` is your second argument, and `selector` is your first argument.